# C# is returning exception: Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I apologise for this formatting. I am new to programming and new to this site, so I will try and make the question as clear as possible.

I have a webform for accessing/modifying a Customer database. I have a button for entering new customers details which will automatically assign an ID number by getting the highest ID number from the database, and incrementing by one (and posting to form textbox).

This is the code I have written:

```
protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Clear();

        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "NewCustomer";

        conn.Open();

        SqlParameter maxid = new SqlParameter();
        maxid.ParameterName = "@MaxID";
        maxid.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        maxid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        command.Parameters.Add(maxid);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();                       

        NewCustId = Convert.ToInt32(maxid.Value);
        NewCustId += 1;

        txtCustID.Text = (NewCustId).ToString();
        txtCustID.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewCustomer
    (@MaxID INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @MaxID = MAX(CustID)
    FROM dbo.Customer
END
```

I have tried many different ways of coding it, but nothing seems to work.
The code I have posted has an exception at `ExecuteNonQuery` saying arguments were supplied and procedure has no parameters. When I place `command.Parameters.Add(maxid);` underneath `ExecuteNonQuery`, it returns a 1.

I ran the SQL Query alone to see what would happen and it returns a correct answer in an unnamed cell. For some reason the Column Name disappears when it comes up. Then when I try to use the C# code to access the unnamed cell, I can't seem to access it because the column 'CustID' "doesn't exist".

With this code, I know that the SQL command is executing, and then the C# code increments by 1, but it seems that the return value I am getting is 0.

I appreciated any ideas that I can get on how to fix this. Thank you.

Edit: I have also tried:
          DataTable table = new DataTable();
          adapter.Fill(table);
          NewCustId = table.Rows[0].Field("CustID");

(This is where it said 'CustID' column didn't exist)

Comment: One word: **DON'T DO THIS!** This will **NOT** work reliably in a busy system - you **will get DUPLICATES** sooner or later! Instead, use the SQL Server buit-in mechanism of an `INT IDENTITY` column that SQL Server itself updates and makes sure not to use any value twice.....

Comment: what is the use of this line `txtCustID.DataBind();` you are already assigning the value to the textbox here `txtCustID.Text = (NewCustId).ToString();` which you could use `txtCustID.Text = Convert.ToString(NewCustId);`

Comment: I know you have several "solutions" posted but you should read and heed the warning from @marc_s. What you are doing is going to fail and cause massive amount of pain in the future.

Comment: all you need to do is the following , edit your stored procedure
`SELECT @MaxID = MAX(CustID) FROM dbo.Customer`

Comment: @marc_s Thankyou for the tip. I understand that it would be an unreliable way of making unique IDs for a busy database. Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with the automated ID system as I'm just a student of this.

Comment: @MethodMan I tried that but it didn't work. Fortunately, there was a solution that did not require parameters at all. Cheers.

Comment: @DaveOli it is better to learn it right at the beginning. if you start with the wrong approach you will find more difficulties changing your mind once your working habit/workflow/mindset is established on the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following and try again:

```
 Clear();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "NewCustomer";
    conn.Open();
    NewCustId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 
    NewCustId += 1;
    txtCustID.Text = NewCustId.ToString();
    conn.Close();
```

And your stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewCustomer
(

)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX(CustID)
     FROM dbo.Customer;
END
```

Comment: @marc_s he tryed to come out with parameter, so I used the parameter to show him

Comment: PERFECT! Thankyou so much. I am new to programming so was hoping there was a nice simple solution.  (P.S. How do I select this as the answer to my post?)

Comment: @DaveOli especially since you are new to programming I will again suggest you abandon this approach. This is a race condition. If you have two people inserting a new row at the same time you will likely get incorrect values back. This is one reason an identity would be a much better approach for this. It is of course your decision but you will feel the pain at some point and it will drive you crazy trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @DaveOli you will regret going this path: your best bet is doing it right even if this application is very small otherwise this will bite your back when you will use the same solution for real world applications and get issues because of concurrency.

Comment: @SeanLange &Paolo Thankyou. Yes, I know it is a bad habit, but I am in very preliminary stages of my learning and am doing web development at the moment. There is a separate SQL course I am doing later on, so I plan to get more into detail regarding good database protocols then. Thankyou.

Comment: @DaveOli by left from my answer you can see the answer score (at a time of this comment it is 0), below this you may see CHECK sign, just click on it

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` expects no results. Try `ExecuteReader()` instead.

Comment: Yes, or `ExectuteScalar()`

Comment: I tried ExecuteReader() and ExecuteScalar() and both got the same exception message.

Answer (score 0):

I second what marc_S is saying about this running into issues.
Since you are using max ID and incrementing by 1 to insert a new record in the database, I suggest that you use Identity(seed, increment_value) for this column.
That way you don't have to find max to insert a new record and you avoid lots of transaction issues.
Once the transaction is done

Possible Design:

```
Create Table Customer
(
    Id Int Identity(1,1), 
    Name varchar(50)
)
Create Proc NewCustomer 
(
    @Name varchar(50)
)
As
(
    DECLARE @custID Int
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Customer (Name) Values('Your Name')
    SET @custID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN @custID
)
protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Clear();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "NewCustomer";

        conn.Open();
        SqlParameter name = new SqlParameter();
        name.ParameterName = "@Name";
        name.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        name.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Varchar;
        name.Value = "Your Name";
        command.Parameters.Add(name);
        SqlParameter returnValue= new SqlParameter();
        returnValue.ParameterName = "@custID";
        returnValue.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(maxid);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();                       

        NewCustId = Convert.ToInt32(returnValue.Value);

        txtCustID.Text = (NewCustId).ToString();
        txtCustID.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a go too, and see if I can get it working. Thankyou!